# Does splitting TEXT fields into multiple tables provide performance optimization in multi-language application?

Tags: mysql, database, query-optimization

I'm building a project and I have a question about mysql databases. The application is multi-language. And we are wondering if you will get better performance if we split up different types of text-fields (varchar, text, med-text) to different tables? Or is it just better to create one table with just a text field?

With this question and the multi-language constraint in mind, I am wondering if the performance will rise of I split up the different types of text fields into seperate tables. Because when you just have one table with all the texts and the language you can search it easily. (Give me the text with this value (in an item column) and that language) When you have different tables for different types of text. You will save space in your database. Because you don't need a full text area for a varchar(200), but you will have multiple tables to create a connection between the item, the type of text and the languages you have for your text.

What do you think is the best? Or are there some possibilities that I didn't used?

Comment: Very difficult to answer your question without some real life examples of the data you will be storing ... and the relationship between the data - please add some more detail to your question

Answer (score 0):

I find it better for performance reasons to keep columns with `blob` and `text` data types in a separate able from the other data types even if it breaks normalization.

Consider a `person` table with columns `name varchar`, `address varchar`, `dob date` and `picture blob`. A picture can be about 1MB easily while the remaining columns may not take any more than 1KB. Imagine how many blokcs of data needed to be read even if you only want to list the name and address of people living in a certain city - if you are keeping everything in the same table.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not bound to MySQL, I would suggest you to use some sort of text-searching engines, such as `Apache Lucene` if you want to do full-text searches. Because as far as I know, MySQL does not provide as much performance as Lucene can for full-text searches.

In case you are bound to MySQL, let me try to provide some information based on current definition of the problem (which is actually not much yet).

[MySQL reference documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/blob.html) states that:

> Instances of BLOB or TEXT columns in the result of a query that is processed using a temporary table causes the server to use a table on disk rather than in memory because the MEMORY storage engine does not support those data types.

So, if you run your queries using `SELECT *` on a table that contains text field, you can either separate queries that really need the text field and the ones that don't need it to gain speed; or alternatively you can separate the text field from the table as well. Saving text field on a secondary table will cause you an extra overhead of the duplicated key storage and also the indexes for that secondary table. However according to your database design, you may also be suffering overhead for unnecessary index updates which can be eliminated by moving the text field to another table, but this is just a proposition since we don't know your schema and data access occasions.